# 404 Not found fixing for changing permalink status

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

In very beginning I used wordpress permalink setting like below.

```
http://www.example.org/sample-post/
```

After adding 20 articles I have changed permalink custom setting like "/%postname%.html". This is why 20 articles are showing 404 not found. In these circumstances, what can I do to solving the 404 not found error? Please assist me..

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing you rewrite rules.

use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/)

then in tools hit 'flush rules'